# How do we extend a single user's session expiration time?

Tags: session, lift, web.xml, session-timeout

I did this in web.xml to regulate the overall session expiration time:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

However, I would try to increase some users' expiration time with the following code:

```
S.session match {
    case Full(session) => {
        session.httpSession match {
            case Full(httpSession) => httpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(2 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
            case _ => log.error("There is no HttpSession in the session")
        }
    }
    case _ => log.error("There is no LiftSession in S.session")
}
```

I was hoping that this piece of code would keep all the SessionVar to live for 2 weeks. It's unfortunately not working. How do we do it instead?

Comment: At first glance that strikes me as a bad idea, and it seems to me like you'd be better off using some type of cache instead. What are you trying to accomplish with a two week session expiration? Also, Lift's `SessionVar` is not stored directly in the session - as Scala functions and other items that may get put there are not serializable. If you want to store things directly with the `HttpSession` - there is `ContainerVar`.

Comment: So, does this mean that as long as I use ContainerVar, the code above would just work?

Comment: Again, not knowing what you are looking to accomplish, I can't say for sure that it would "just work". However, if you use `ContainerVar` you will have a mechanism that is tied to the servlet container's session. However, you will need to provide your own serializer so that Lift can serialize your data to the container. It also assumes that your container has support for sessions that last 2 weeks, and also that there are no memory or garbage collection issues. But, if your servlet container can support it, changing your `SessionVar` to `ContainerVar` and implementing a serializer should work.